# How to input arguments from R to Python with rPython?

Tags: python, r, parameter-passing, rpython

**How to input arguments from R to Python with the package rPython?**

Below is a naive attempt

In script.py:

```
print message
```

In script.R:

```
require(rPython)    
text = "Hello World"
python.load("script.py", message=text)

Error in python.load("script.py", message = text) : 
  unused argument (message = text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the package's [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/rPython.pdf) (page 5-6) for the `load` method:

> This function runs Python code contained in a file. Typically, this
>   file would contain functions to be called via python.call or other
>   functions in this package.

Hence, do not have a running script in Python but only defined functions with return objects:

**Python** *(script.py)*

```
def print_message(msg):
   return msg
```

**R** *(using load and call)*

```
require(rPython)    
text = "Hello World"

python.load("script.py")
python.call("print_message", text)

#[1] "Hello World"
```